# Tensorflow shuffle_batch from multiple files breaks labelling

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to write my own MNIST digits classifier using Tensorflow and I am stuck with a tf.train.shuffle_batch function's weird behaviour.

The problem appears when I am trying to load images and labels from different files, shuffle batch seems to shuffle both labels and images on their own, therefore producing bad labeled data. The data was taken from [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

Is it a defined behaviour for shuffle_batch function? 
How would you suggest dealing with such situations when data and labels are different files?

Here is my code

```
DATA = 'train-images.idx3-ubyte'
LABELS = 'train-labels.idx1-ubyte'
data_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([DATA,])
label_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([LABELS,])

NUM_EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 10

reader_data = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=28*28, header_bytes = 16)
reader_labels = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=1, header_bytes = 8)

(_,data_rec) = reader_data.read(data_queue)
(_,label_rec) = reader_labels.read(label_queue)

image = tf.decode_raw(data_rec, tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28, 1])
label = tf.decode_raw(label_rec, tf.uint8)
label = tf.reshape(label, [1])


image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label],
                                                 batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                 capacity=100,
                                                 min_after_dequeue = 30)


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

image = image_batch[1]
im = image.eval()
print("im_batch shape :" + str(image_batch.get_shape().as_list()))
print("label shape :" + str(label_batch.get_shape().as_list()))
print("label is :" + str(label_batch[1].eval()))
# print("output is :" + str(conv1.eval()))

plt.imshow(np.reshape(im, [-1, 28]), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem arises because you evaluate `image` and `label_batch[1]` in separate [`Tensor.eval()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval) calls. This means that you are getting values from two different batches. If instead you write:

```
im, lbl = sess.run([image_batch[1], label_batch[1]])
```

...you should get a matching image and label from the same batch.